# How to query FQL Stream by Attachment.Media.Type?

Tags: hyperlink, stream, facebook-fql

When I query the stream table, how do I use attachment.media.type in a WHERE clause?  The type field that is the sibling to attachment is always null and I've read that it was deprecated so that is why I want to access the one inside of attachment.

The structure of the attachment field array is:

```
      "attachment": {
        "name": "My Title",
        "media": [
          {
            "href": "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
            "alt": "",
            "type": "link",
            "src": "http://somephotourlhere"
          }
        ]
```

I'd want to do something like this (which does not work):

```
WHERE attachment.media["type"] = "link"
```

Answer (score 4):

The `attachment.media` field is an array. To the best of my knowledge, FQL can't return values from inside an array.

If you want to find links you can use `AND type = 80` in your FQL.

However, Posted photos also have a type = 80. To filter these out, add

```
AND type = 80 AND attachment.fb_object_type != 'photo'
```

or

```
AND type = 80 AND strlen(attachment.fb_object_type) < 1
```

to protect against future objects that may also return type = 80. For links, `attachment.fb_object_type` is undefined.